# Hide banner "Update your license key because it will expire in x days"

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am getting this banner on every Page of my Liferay portal:

> Update your license key because it will expire in 27 days. Visit your profile page at Liferay.com to upgrade your trial license.

The banner hides vital parts of the page, so I have to close it every time, which takes a substantial amount of time. It is just a matter of time until a new license is ordered, but it could take two weeks if my company's buying department is busy.

How to make Liferay 7 not show this banner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a longstanding [open issue](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-30827). You may want to vote for it, or file it through your EE support. I'd say, a quick fix for it (although it's quite definitive - make sure to revert it when no longer needed) is to identify the CSS for this method and "CSS - display:none" it.

I'd hope that the message will soon pop up only once per session and then stay hidden after been acknowledged once.

Another alternative: Do not use an Administrator account to log in, rather a less privileged one, where the message doesn't get shown.